# Melee vs. short Blaster in SWEotE?

Tags: combat, combat-maneuver, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars

We had a situation where my blaster pistol wielding character was attacked by a opponent with a melee weapon.

What ensued was that the opponent closed into melee range and attacked,  then on my turn I used my maneuver to disengage to short range an fire the blaster. Rinse repeat.

This seemed a bit of a weird fighting scene.

It wasn't such a big deal,  but afterwards we were wondering whether we missed something in the rules or in the options the characters had that would've made this more ...  cinematic?

Comment: keep posting EotE questions, we need to get more visibility for it on the site. Also if you have something more casual that doesn't seem up to par for a question don't hesitate to ask me in [chat]

Comment: @joshua - he :-) have to switch from player to GM next week,  so currently taking a closer look at things.

Answer (score 4):

**What happened is actually quite normal for a short range vs melee combat.**

Most melee weapons need to be engaged to work and your blaster pistol is optimum at short range, both PCs and all enemies have 1 free maneuver on their turn so the back and forth you describe happens a lot.

The core combat system of EotE is mean tot be quick and simplistic because the focus of the system is on story so you won't find a lot of mechanical depth to plumb beyond letting players narrate actions and then imposing skill checks on them.

**How to make things better**

PCs can take strain to perform extra maneuvers on their turn. Your players can be taking this strain to move shoot move to evade the melee fighters more effectively. Beyond that your players can try to do things like kick over tables or climb up in the rafters or otherwise impede melee attacks to spice things up.

Beyond that maybe that PC with the blaster pistol tries to shoot out a critical piece of the building to change the nature of the fight. Think about how Triumph symbols can be used in this way (shooting a door closed for example) and instead let players try to achieve similar results by making a check with the appropriate difficulty.